# Convolution of a compactly supported $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with a function $g \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lp-spaces, convolution

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are two $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^n)$-functions. Their convolution is well-defined under many conditions, three of which are:

1. When $f$ is compactly supported and continuous, and $g$ is just $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
2. When $f$ and $g$ are in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n).$
3. When $f$ and $g$ are in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n).$

There are many more. However, I'm wondering whether the following is true:

> If $f,g \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ are such that $f$ is compactly supported (thus also in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$), then $f * g$ is well-defined almost everywhere. Also, do I then have $f * g \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

The proof of $1.$ doesn't go through: it's based on the fact that $f$ is bounded, and I don't have that if $f$ is not continuous. The proof of $2.$ that I've found goes along the following lines: let $H(x,y) := f(x-y)g(y).$ Then $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2n}} |H(x,y)|dxdy = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(x-y)|dx \right) |g(y)| dy = ||f||_1 \cdot ||g||_1, $$so by Fubini, the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x-y)g(y)dy$ exists and is integrable for a.e. $y \in \mathbb{R}^n.$ However, in my case, $H$ is not necessarily integrable.

It's hard to think of a counterexample, because we'd need $f$ to be **so discontinuous** as to ruin the local integrability of $g$ on a set of positive measure! I can easily do it at one point, (for example $f(y) = g(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}$ at $x = 0$), or even at a countable set of points (think of infinitely many "volcanoes" of the above type converging to zero), but doing it for a large enough set of points seems very hard to me.

Comment: I'm confused. You say that $f$ need not be bounded since it's not continuous, but $(1)$ inherently assumes that $f$ is continuous and compactly supported (and thus bounded). Your proof for $(2)$ also probably needs to have a $\le$ instead of $=$ on the first part.

Comment: In the criterion that I'm trying to prove/disprove, $f$ is not continuous. It's just $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and compactly supported, thus also $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, but not necessarily bounded.

Comment: OHHHH I get you now. You're saying if you try to apply the previous approaches, various things fail. My bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Hoping I didn't make a mistake here..) If $f$ has compact support and is locally integrable, then $f$ is actually integrable (take compact $K$ such that $\operatorname{supp}(f)\subseteq K$) which will make $f*g$ locally integrable. Let $K$ be compact, then

$$\int_K |(f*g)(x)|\,dx = \int_K \bigg|\int_{\operatorname{supp}(f)}f(y)g(x-y)\,dy\bigg|\,dx \le \int_K \int_{\operatorname{supp}(f)}|f(y)||g(x-y)|\,dy\,dx.$$

By Fubini-Tonelli, we can interchange these even if it diverges to infinity, so

$$\int_K |(f*g)(x)|\,dx \le \int_{\operatorname{supp}(f)}|f(y)|\int_K |g(x-y)|\,dx\,dy.$$

The $x$ integral is finite since $g$ is locally integrable and $K+y$ is also a compact set. The $y$ integral is finite since $f$ is actually just straight up integrable.

Comment: Could you state what version of Fubini-Tonelli you're using? The one I know requires $$\int_{K \times \text{supp}(f)} |f(y)g(x-y)|dxdy < +\infty.$$If this is the one you're using, could you elaborate on why this integral converges?

Comment: I should clarify that Tonelli holds true regardless of finiteness (meaning you can integrate in whichever order and get the same, possibly infinite, result). Here our functions are positive by virtue of taking absolute values. However it doesn't actually matter because the final integral is finite, so backtracking with regular Fubini-Tonelli, the interchange is justified.

Comment: Ah, I see it on Wikipedia now. My Fubini-skills got a bit rusty. Thanks for the great answer! And, in particular, this implies that $f*g(x)$ exists for almost every $x$, in the same way as in the proof of version $2.$ in my question?

Comment: It should since it's locally integrable, yes. Also: don't feel bad about Fubini-Tonelli, I believe Wikipedia is actually *very* poorly-written on this front. It's extremely confusing and also misleading in my opinion.